# Two different ways to open a project in IDE's for MCUs

Tags: arm, texas-instruments, st, ide, iar

I am using following 3 different IDE's for ARM based MCU's.

1. [TI's CCS](https://www.ti.com/tool/CCSTUDIO)
2. [ST's CubeIDE](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeide.html)
3. [IAR's Workbench](https://www.iar.com/iar-embedded-workbench/#!?architecture=Arm)

I have to move the entire projects which are build on each of these IDE's on different PC's from time to time.

One thing I have noticed is that I can easily open an IAR project when I move it on another PC by simply double clicking on its .eww project file but for CCS and CubeIDE projects I had to go through the File->Import steps in their respective IDE's.

It works but I am curious why these two IDE's have entirely different way to open a project which was build on some other PC?

Is it possible to open a CCS project or a CubeIDE project just by clicking a single file.. same as in the case of IAR? In IAR when I double-click its .eww file then it open the entire project in the IDE and setup the folders all by itself. If I trying to figure out a similar way in CCS and CudeIDE.

Comment: Maybe because they are producing different format files? Every development environment has its own files to handle the project. But generally, gcc is used to compile, link, relocate the base project. You may wanna look at Makefile tool of gcc.

Comment: I am trying to find a similar way in CCS and CubeIDE as its there in the IAR.. ie., just by double-clicking a single file (.eww in IAR) it opens the entire project inside the IDE and shows all project files in it.

Comment: This is a software problem - have you tried right-click -> "Open With" on the file? That should set it up for repeated use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IAR is a proprietary IDE solution, where CCS and STM32CubeIDE buth use the open source project [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/) as foundation.

IAR uses project files, Eclipse uses workspace folders.
Two completely different approaches with each their advantages or disadvantages.

One of which is that you can't double-click on a folder and open it in a program.

---

*Perhaps there is some shortcut/bash file you can use that calls up the IDE with arguments to open some workspace*